# Why won't my Windows 7 run Tortoise SVN?

Tags: windows-7, tortoise-svn

well i have another computer (windows vista) and i have this computer, i already know how to run SVN tortoise, the problem i am having is when i right click on my desktop or on the folder i want to svn checkout/update on, none of the svn options are coming up. however i know i have it installed (C:) and have tried installing it into C:\Program Files (x86) neither one of them seem to work (i did un-install from program files (x86) before i re-installed in just C:)

Here is a screen shot so I can help out giving y'all some answers:

[image]

Comment: Voted to move to SU; TortoiseSVN works fine on my Win7/64 box

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have a Program Files (x86) directory indicates that you have a 64-bit system. Are you using the x64 version?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with idealmachine above: you must install the 64-bit version of Tortoise to see it in Windows Explorer. The exception to this rule is if you use 32-bit apps that give you access to the shell menu (NuSphere's PHPEd is one that springs to mind) as these will only show the 32-bit version of Tortoise. Luckily, you can have both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of TortoiseSVN installed at the same time and they do not interfere with each other.